# Link Android Button and WebView - possible?

Tags: javascript, android, button, webview

I have an Activity that contains an Android Button and a webView that contains a button that opens a new URL:

```
window.location.href = "deals.html?subCategoryId=" + subCategoryId;
```

Is it possible for the Android button to allow the user to move back to the first webView after the above line has been executed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `goBack()` method on the web view to navigate back to the previous page:

```
if (myWebView.canGoBack()) // Verify there is a page to navigate to...
{
    myWebView.goBack(); // Navigates the webview backwards one page.
}
```

Put the above code into the click handler for the button that will control this behaviour.

See:

1. [Android WebView Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). Specifically [goBack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#goBack%28%29) and [canGoBack()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#canGoBack%28%29).